# C++: Implementing a copyable polymorphic wrapper

Tags: c++

I want to implement a Wrapper Class for polymorphic types, that has value semantics - similar to the ones in the Proposals [P0201](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0201r6.html) and [P3019](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p3019r0.pdf). The gist is that for a class `Base` and its derived class `Derived`, the Wrapper `Poly<Base>` can be filled with a `Derived` and upon copying `Poly<Base>`, a (deep) copy of `Derived` is created.

The implementation essentially boils down to using a clonable control block:

```cpp
struct BaseControl<BaseType>
{
   virtual auto clone() -> BaseControl<BaseType>* = 0;
   virtual auto object() -> BaseType* = 0;
};

struct Control<BaseType, DerivedType> : public BaseControl<BaseType>
{
   auto clone() -> BaseControl<BaseType>* {return new Control(*this);}
   auto object() -> BaseType* {return std::addressof(object);}
   
   DerivedType object;
};

struct Poly<BaseType> 
{
   Poly(InPlace<DerivedType>) : control{new Control<BaseType, DerivedType>()} {}
   Poly(Poly const& other) : control{other.control->clone()} {}

   BaseControl<BaseType>* control;
};
```

*For the sake of brevity, this code is boiled down to slideware. Please ignore the missing template keywords, special member functions, memory leaks, ...*

Now P0201 allows a `Poly<Base>` to be created from a `Poly<Derived>`. In the [reference implementation](https://github.com/jbcoe/polymorphic_value/blob/main/polymorphic_value.h), this is achieved via a delegating control block. This is essentially:

```cpp
struct DelegatingControl<BaseType, DerivedType> : public BaseControl<BaseType>
{
   auto clone() -> BaseControl<BaseType>* {return new DelegatingControl(subControl->clone());}
   auto object() -> BaseType* {return subControl->object();}
   
   BaseControl<DerivedType>* subControl;
};
```

But this means that every copy/ move from a derived class introduces another layer of indirection. My question is whether this can be circumvented?

The way I see it, we have to remove the BaseType from the BaseControl.

```cpp
struct BaseControl
{
   virtual auto clone() -> BaseControl* = 0;
   virtual auto object_address() -> void* = 0;
};

struct Control<DerivedType> : public BaseControl
{
   auto clone() -> BaseControl* {return new Control<DerivedType>(*this);}
   auto object_address() -> void* {return std::addressof(object);}
   
   DerivedType object;
};
```

But now the problem is correctly accessing the object after cloning. Essentially, we need to know the offset from `BaseControl` to the relevant Type.

```cpp
struct Poly<BaseType>
{
   Poly(InPlace<DerivedType>) :
      control{new Control<DerivedType>()}, 
      ptr{static_cast<DerivedType*>(control->object_address())} 
   {}

   BaseControl* control;
   BaseType* ptr;
};

// (move) constructor from DerivedType is trivial
Poly<BaseType>(Poly<DerivedType> other)
{
   control = std::exchange(other.control, nullptr);
   ptr = std::exchange(other.ptr, nullptr);
}

// Copy Constructor is hard
Poly<BaseType>(Poly<BaseType> const& other)
{
   control = other.control->clone();
   auto offset = (void*) other.ptr - other.control->object_address(); // allowed?
   ptr = (BaseType*)(control->object_address() + offset);             // allowed?
}
```

Aside from arithmetic on `void*` not being allowed (though this could be circumvented by casting the addresses to `unsigned char*`), this code should Work. Both `*control` and `*other.control` are objects of type `Control<SomeDerivedClass>`, which have a member `SomeDerivedClass`. In turn, this member is derived from `Derived`, which we can access by adding an offset to the member address. However, I am unsure whether this introduces undefined/ unspecified behavior.

Another option would be to replace the `BaseType*` with a pointer to member `BaseType BaseControl::*`. Alas the standard does not allow for casting this pointer to `Derived BaseControl::*`, which breaks the constructor from `Poly<Derived>`.

A third option would be to require all Types to be derived from some dummy baseclass, but this is not an elegant solution.

Comment: "this code should Work" -- up until you introduce virtual inheritance somewhere.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't see how virtual inheritance could pose a problem here. Since the most derived class is the same in the control block and its clone, any virtual inheritance offsets that are applied during a static_cast are the same for both instances. The two sequences of static_casts should both lead to the same offset.

Comment: Ahh but what happens if you initialize a `Poly<Derived>` from a `MoreDerived*`, then convert to `Poly<DiamondBase>` ?  Perhaps that's a violation of a precondition on `Poly<>` but it's allowed by the C++ rules (provided that `Derived` has a polymorphic destructor)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to implement the construction approach of P3019. Only Poly itself can construct an element, you can't construct a Poly<Type> from a Type*.

Comment: In practice that's probably sufficient to ensure that the layouts, and therefore the relative offsets, are identical.  But the resulting pointer still is not safely derived and using it is undefined behavior (which `std::launder` might work around).

Comment: @BenVoigt Alright, I was hoping to find a more elegent solution, but it seems to works.